# 日本語に違和感: アカウント作成後初めて質問を開いたときの表示（？）の説明

Tags: バグ, 対応予定, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

全体的に違和感があります。翻訳しようと思うのですが原文はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

英語は下記です：

> #### Your Answer
>
> Thanks for contributing an answer to Stack Overflow!
>
> - Please be sure to answer the question.
> - Provide details and share your research!
>
> But *avoid* …
>
> - Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
> - Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
> - To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

---

仮翻訳：

> #### 回答
>
> スタック・オーバーフローに回答を投稿していただきありがとうございます！
>
> - 質問に対する答えになっているかどうかを確認してください
> - あなたが調べたことや、回答の根拠などの詳細も書いてください
>
> 次のような回答は避けてください：
>
> - 追加の質問や、ほかの回答へのコメント
> - 資料や経験に裏付けられていない、主観的な意見や感想
>
> 良い回答の仕方については[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)も参照してください。

Comment: この文章はTransifex上にないようですが、登録していただくことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: @unarist Transifexにない場合、簡単に追加することはできません。開発者と確認してみます。